# Android Activity Loop

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

I have been making a SurfaceView class in android and have been drawing to a canvas every frame. I have done so using the

```
onDraw()
```

@Override method in the SurfaceView class.

My issue is that the bitmap that is being drawn to the canvas needs to have it's position dynamically changed every frame. I wish to do the changing of the x and y position from the main Activity and pass it to the SurfaceView through an x and a y property of the SurfaceView.

I need the x and y to change every frame, so I made a Runnable  Thread. For some reason when the thread runs in the main loop the onDraw doesn't loop anymore. Somehow the 2 loops are conflicting and not letting the other run (the runnable and onDraw can't run at the same time).

I have no idea why this is happening and I think it is probably an easy solution, I just can't figure what the solution is. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to post some more code.

Comment: If you're overriding `onDraw()`, you should be using a custom View, not a SurfaceView.  The point of the SurfaceView is the separately composited drawing surface you get from SurfaceHolder#lockCanvas().  For custom views, see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!